# android code acting differently on device than emulator

Tags: android

hi i developed a simple app that should play a sound if a boolean is true and then another sound when it completes or just play the second sound if the boolean is false and it all works perfectly on the avd but when run on device it doesint let the first sound complete before jumping to the second

this is in the onCreate

```
setContentView(screen);//pl
if(msg==true) {//boolean set from other activity
    playInfo();
}else if(msg==false){
    playSound();
  }
}
```

this is the play info method which starts to play but after a second it jumps to playsound method on the phone but works perfectly on avd

```
private void playInfo(){
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.msg);
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            msg = false;
            playSound();
        }
    });
}
```

this is the playsound method

```
 private void playSound() {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, song);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                playSound();//loop the sound
            }
        });
    }
```

again this works perfect on emulator but not on a device why would they act differently and any ideas on how it would be resolved?

Comment: What exactly does the device do differently than the emulator?

Comment: Add mp.stop(); and mp.release()  inside onCompletion of both the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The activity was set to landscape mode on the device this caused the activity to be redrawn very quickly after launching so it started got destroyed and started again with the boolean set to false however on the emulator this does not happen it just draws the activity once in landscape mode solved the problem by using 2 different mediaplayers and just play the first short sound over the other rather than rework the code.